# How can I create a 3D array made of more than one object in Python?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I know that if I wanted to create a 3D array in Python, I could do this:

`[[['#' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)] for k in range(3)]`

That said, what if I wanted to include another symbol in the 3D array?
For example, what if I wanted to alternate between '#' and '-' in the array? Or what if I wanted two '#''s in a row, followed by a '-'. How could I write that?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
import itertools
it = itertools.cycle(['#', '-', '#'])
print([[[next(it) for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)] for k in range(3)])
```

Output:

```
[[['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#']], [['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#']], [['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> [[['#' if i%2==0 else '-' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
[[['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#']], [['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#']], [['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#'], ['#', '-', '#']]]
```

Comment: Really appreciate this! Not sure why I didn't think of something like this. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `i`, and insert `#` if its `< 2`; otherwise put `-`:

```
[[['#' if i < 2 else '-' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
```

To alternate, just use modulus:

```
[[['#' if i % 2 == 0 else '-' for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)] for k in range(3)]
```

Comment: This is super helpful and makes a ton of sense! Thanks so much!